# Xamarin Forms- How to overlap the frames and highlight the selected frame?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a requirement that I need to overlap two frames and on clicking any frame show the complete frame on top of the other.

Below is the code I'm using to achieve my requirement

```
<Frame
    CornerRadius="30"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    HasShadow="False"
    Padding="0">

    <Grid
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Frame
            x:Name="addressbook_frame"
            TranslationX="30"
            Grid.Column="0"
            CornerRadius="30"
            Padding="0">

            <Label
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Text="Address Book"
                TextColor="White"/>
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Tapped="AddressBookTapped"
                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                </TapGestureRecognizer>
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        </Frame>

        <Frame
            x:Name="phonebook_frame"
            TranslationX="-30"
            Grid.Column="1"
            CornerRadius="30">

            <Label
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Text="Phone Book"
                TextColor="White"/>
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Tapped="PhoneBookTapped"
                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                </TapGestureRecognizer>
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
```

[This is the outcome of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEsw8.png)

[My requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjcAA.png)

Is there any better approach to overlap two frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Raise/LowerChild` of `Grid` to achieve this effect.

```
<Grid
    x:Name = "grid"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Frame
        x:Name="addressbook_frame"
        TranslationX="30"
        Grid.Column="0"
        CornerRadius="30"
        Padding="0">

        <Label
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="Address Book"
            TextColor="White"/>
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="AddressBookTapped"
                NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
            </TapGestureRecognizer>
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    </Frame>

    <Frame
        x:Name="phonebook_frame"
        TranslationX="-30"
        Grid.Column="1"
        CornerRadius="30">

        <Label
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="Phone Book"
            TextColor="White"/>
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="PhoneBookTapped"
                NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
            </TapGestureRecognizer>
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

in page.cs:

```
 private void AddressBookTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grid.RaiseChild(addressbook_frame);
    }
 private void PhoneBookTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grid.RaiseChild(phonebook_frame);
    }
```